# How to compile a Linux kernel >= 4.1 for Mint 17.3

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, linux-mint

I need to build and install a Linux kernel >= 4.1 in order to get my Wi-Fi working. I want to use Linux Mint (17.3). I found instructions about how to change the kernel on mintguide.org (https://mintguide.org/system/580-install-linux-kernel-4-4-4-stable-on-linux-mint.html)

I tried to build several kernel images but I always run into the same problem: during the build process the `gcc` compiler complains about some implicit function declarations. Since I have this problem with several kernel versions, I assume I'm missing some requirement. The build machine is running a Mint distribution with `build-essentials` package installed. The `gcc` compiler is version 4.9.3, due to missing `-fstack-protector-strong` parameter, which is required for building kernel 4.4.4.

One problem with kernel 4.4.4 is for example that '__vmalloc' is only implicitly declared in /var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.59/build/loader.c:156:19

Is there anything I can do without changing the code? Can I alter the -Werror compile flag?

Comment: Questions about **building** software, especially required some configuration or specific compiler options, are perfectly **on-topic** on SO. Not sure why this question has been closed.

Comment: `#include` the header file <linux/vmalloc.h>

Comment: the referenced web page discusses how to download/install/activate a new 'mint' kernel image.  it says nothing about obtaining the source files, how to compile the kernel.  How are you actually compiling the kernel?

Comment: Rather than a link to 'how to switch kernels, a better link would be: `https://www.howtoforge.com/kernel_compilation_ubuntu` which discusses, step by step, how to compile/link the kernel.

Comment: Many thanks for rephrasing my question and your comments. I chose to take a different approach and went with ubuntu 15.10.